# Java - how to delete elements with the same property value from collection?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, collections

Assume there's a Collection of SomeClass elements with SomeField property. How to delete repetitive elements with equivalent SomeField properties from this Collection and retain only one element with that SomeField value?

Comment: I have got three words for you - iterator, getter, for(Type obj:list)

Comment: Take a look at java.uti.Set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few simple approaches to solve this.

If the `SomeField` value is the only member of `SomeClass` then you can easily override `hashCode` and `equals` in `SomeClass` based on `SomeField` and then simply add your original collection to a `HashSet`.

If this is not the case and `SomeClass` is more complex you can still use a `Set`. However, you need to filter out the duplicates somehow and one good approach is using a `Comparator` together with a `TreeSet`.

```
// Create a new Set with a specified comparator
final Collection<SomeClass> someClasses = 
        new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(SomeClass::getSomeField));

// Add all elements from the original collection (duplicates will be removed)
someClasses.addAll(originalColl);
```

The `Comparator.comparing` method creates a `Comparator`. If you are not using Java 8 a non-lambda `Comparator` can be used as well:

```
Comparator<SomeClass> comparator = new Comparator<SomeClass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final SomeClass o1, final SomeClass o2) {
        // Do some kind of compare-operation. If SomeField is 
        // Comparable you can do it this way:
        return o1.getSomeField().compareTo(o2.getSomeField());
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works, it's worth pointing out that this assumes that `SomeField implements Comparable<SomeField>`. Also, `TreeSet` has `O(lg n)` `add` complexity, which might be an issue if there is a lot of data being processed. Conversely, a `HashSet` has `O(1)` `add`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, correct. Totally depends on the amount of data that is to be processed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement hashCode and equals for SomeClass so that only SomeField is taken into account.

```
class SomeClass {
  private SomeField field;
  public int hashCode() {
    return field.hashCode();
  }
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof SomeClass == false){
      return false
    }
    SomeClass someClass = (SomeClass)o;
    return someClass.field.equals(this.field)

  }
}
```

Now you can put everything into Set in order to remove duplicates

```
Set set = new HashSet(collection);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java collections have an *optional* `remove` method. Assuming the collection you're working on supports it you can use it:

> `boolean remove(Object o)`
>
> Removes a single instance of the specified element from this collection, if it is present (optional operation).

Assuming the collection has an `add` method, you can  run a loop removing the element from the collection while it is present (check using `contains`) and once it does not have the element `add` it.

```
while(myCollection.contains(el)){
    myCollection.remove(el);
}
myCollection.add(el);
```

Then again - it is probably better to just create a `Set` from the collection (by passing it to the `TreeSet` constructor for instance) - sets are guaranteed to only have a single instance of each element.

```
Set unique = new TreeSet(myCollection); // assumes comparable
Set unique2 = new HashSet(myCollection); // assumes hashCode
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Map`.

Dump everything into a `Map` keyed by `SomeField` (assuming `SomeField` has well defined `equals` and `hashCode`) then take `Map.values`.

If you want to retain the **last** duplicate encountered:

```
final Collection<SomeClass> filtered = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(SomeClass::getKey, identity()))
        .values();
```

Or, if you want the **first** duplicate countered:

```
final HashMap<Integer, SomeClass> mapped = list.stream()
        .collect(HashMap::new, (m, s) -> m.merge(s.getKey(), s, (l, r) -> l), HashMap::putAll);
final Collection<SomeClass> filtered = mapped.values();
```

In the second case, the type inference system needs a little help, so you need to assign the intermediate `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

`Collections` class doesn't have a direct `remove` method. You can implement `Collection` interface and implement `remove` method, or use one of the other implementations (LinkedList, Set, ArrayList, etc.);

The following is a pseudocode, but you can adapt it to your needs:

```
Collection<YourType> list = new ArrayList<>();

// Add your objects to it - to make your collection
for (YourType T: ArrayOfYourType)
    list.add(T);

// Remove elements from the list

for (YourType T: list)
    if T.getSomeProps() == equals(your_val){  // Or equals()
        list.remove(T);
    }
```

You can also list them using map pairs, but that might be an overkill for what you are trying to do.